# Why is code writen in functional programming language shorter than code writen in other programming paradigm languages?

Tags: functional-programming, paradigms

Many people say that code writen in functional programming language is shorter than code writen in other programming paradigm languages.But why?

Comment: There are methods of abstraction in a functional language and of course often already implemented. OO languages has similar features like iterator and perhaps generators. I'm not certain that functional programming is shorter against a properly though out OO equivalent. (BTW: My favorite languages are LISPs)

Answer (score 2):

One big reason is the greater use of higher-order functions. A simple example is `map`. The following are equivalent:

```
# Procedural psuedocode
result = []
for value in other_list:
    add somefunc(value) to result

# Functional pseudocode
let result = map(somefunc, other_list)
```

The higher-order function `map` abstracts away the code that iterates over the first list and sequentially adds the function return value to the new list. Other higher-order functions can be used to implement other techniques that are commonly spelled out (whether by necessity or not) in more detail in other paradigms.

---

Another less commonly seen higher-order function is composition. In many languages, you write code like

```
def new_function(x):
    return func2(func1(x))

value = new_function(5)
```

or

```
lambda x: func2(func1(x))
```

In a functional style, you would write (or have) a `compose` function to handle the details, instead of having to write each composed function individually.

```
def compose(f, g):
    def _(x):
        return f(g(x))

value = compose(func2, func1)(x)
```

Some languages, like Haskell, even provide a composition operator:

```
value = (func2 . func1)(x)
```